# Kubernetes Command Based Liveness Probes

Tags: kubernetes, livenessprobe

I have a file in `/tmp/healthy` as mentioned in official documentation and YAML is available

```
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - cat
    - /tmp/healthy
```

But in my case file always be here and it will contain message like Success or Failure

It is possible with `livenessProbe:command` to behave on these messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of a liveness probe is usually just to check if a pod is up and reachable. `cat` is decent command to use for liveness probes because it always returns success as long as the file is there. It is just checking if Kubelet can reach the pod.

If I'm understanding what you mean though, it is possible to have the result of the liveness probe depend on the contents of the file. You can execute any bash and exit with a 1 or 0 (fail or suceed) to control the result you want.

For example, if you want the liveness probe to fail if your file contains any failure message:

```
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - /bin/bash
        - '-c'
        - grep -zqv "Failure" file.txt
```

Comment: this worked for me 
command:    
   - /bin/grep
        - -zqv
        - "Failure"
        - /opt/microservices/health

Answer (score 4):

yes, you can use the `grep` command to search for `Success` string, if it is found it would return `0`(passing the probe) , however if `Success` string is not found by `grep` it would return `non-zero` rc(failing the probe)

```
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - grep
    - Success 
    - /tmp/healthy
```

As per documentation

> If the command succeeds, it returns 0, and the kubelet considers the
> container to be alive and healthy. If the command returns a non-zero
> value, the kubelet kills the container and restarts it.

This means, `exec` type depends on the return code of the command. as long as `grep` is returning success , probe will pass.  In shell return code of any command can be manually checked via `$?` variable. Eg: :

```
grep Success /tmp/healthy; echo $?
```